# How to validate bitwise values?

Tags: php, security, validation, binary, bit-manipulation

In database table I have column called `options`. It has type of integer and it supposed to hold sum of bitwise values that comes from user input. User sends array of bitwise values like `[1, 2, 4, 8]` to server, then values are summed-up and saved in that column. When I need to output values — I just check like `$options & 2`. It all works fine, but I'm just wondering: Do I need somehow check user input before saving sum of bitwise values in the database?

Thanks in any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short and simple:
one should **always** check user input. always.

in you case, you should check the different values *before* summing them up or doing anything else using them. if everything is ok (only numbers that are powers of 2), sum them up and process the result (save to database / whatever else).

Answer (score 0):

The problems you would probably face with user input bitwise values that were not checked are the same problems you would face with any type of data that didn't get checked after a submit.

So yes, you should **always** check and validate your user input data.